# Sum of Multiple JQuery Sliders Updates another Slider

Tags: jquery, slider

I am trying to make a page where I have 5 jquery sliders.   Moving Sliders 1,2,3 & 4 should update Slider 5.  The value of Slider 5 is simply and average of the four sliders.

Here is my attempt (http://jsfiddle.net/drmiles/sHzcM/).  But I can seem to get the 5 sliders to update.  I've spent hours on this and could really use the help of a more experienced in jquery.

http://jsfiddle.net/drmiles/sHzcM/

Thanks,
Miles

Answer (score 0):

This is the simple solution:

```
var slideVal4 = Math.round((slideVal0 + slideVal1 + slideVal2 + slideVal3) / 4);
```

You have to calculate the average for the first 4 sliders and update the 5th one. Additionaly you should disable the 5th slider.

Here an updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sHzcM/2/).